# Speex echo cancellation takes a long time (~20s) to converge

Tags: speech, adaptive-filters

I have been experimenting with [Speex's echo canceller](https://speex.org/docs/manual/speex-manual/node7.html#SECTION00740000000000000000) during the past few days.

I got the echo canceller to work, however, it takes a long time until it actually begins filtering out the echo. It seems like the adaptive filter takes a long time (~20s) to converge for some reason, after which it works quite well. I'm using a tail length of 100ms, but I tried changing that to shorter (and longer) - doesn't help.

Therefore I was thinking maybe I should save a working echo state to file, and read that everytime I start the app, instead of initialising an empty one every time. Does anyone have any experience with that? Speex has no built-in functionality to do that so I'm wondering whether this is even the right approach?

Comment: how do you parameterice the echo canceller? Which `frame_length`, which `filter_length` value do you choose?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `SpeexEchoState` used with every single call from the echo [cancelling API](https://speex.org/docs/api/speex-api-reference/group__SpeexEchoState.html) is exactly the state you'd want to save/restore, so uh, I'd say, yes, Speex does have a way of getting/setting echo cancellation state. Of course, it doesn't do IO for that – not its job, kind of.

Comment: Then on secon thought, `SpeexEchoState_` is pretty opaque, and contains pointer types. You might need to look into storing/restoring the right things only.

Comment: hey @MarcusMüller, frame length is my buffer size, so 512 samples, and filter length is 100ms (samplerate/10). Sampling rate is 44100. I agree that speex shouldn't provide us the serialization/deserialization functions, but if this is a common thing to do then I would have expected to see some functions that would allow us to set the impulse response.

Comment: Something similar to the `SPEEX_ECHO_SET_SAMPLING_RATE` macro but for the impulse response..

Comment: @nevos, quite a while ago since this question was asked, I know. ;-) But have you finally been able improve the learning phase of the AEC. I'm experiencing the same issue. Generally the SpeexDsp AEC works very well, but it takes very long until it starts working well.